# How to get primary key from another table with one-to-many relationship in embedded code in django

Tags: mysql, django, pythonanywhere

I'm not sure exactly how to ask this question, so apologies in advance if it doesn't make a lot of sense.

I'm creating a basic blogging-type website using pythonanywhere, and want each user to have a profile page. In the page that displays a list of all posts, I have the author of each post displayed like so in a

```
{% for post in posts %}:
    <p>author: {{ post.author }}</p>
```

Assuming that all my urls, views and templates are fine, how do I add a link to that text which would lead to `/accounts/[user's id]`?

The Post model's author field is defined as

```
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

Essentially I want:

```
<p>author: <a href="{% url 'account_detail' pk=User.pk %}">{{ post.author }}</a></p>
```

But I don't know how to actually get User.pk from post.author.

Comment: Did you try `pk=post.author.pk` ?

Comment: @IvanMiljkovic I thought I had but apparently not..now I feel stupid! Thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have this model:

> author=models.ForeignKey('HERE IS ENOUGH THE MODEL)

and the ForeignKey is in a model named POST

for access the id of the table just write:

```
post.author__pk
```

By the way is always better do this operation in the view.py like:

```
value = post.objects.values('name', 'author__pk').filter(filter if necessary)
```

Answer (score 0):

How @Ivan Miljkovic explained, it is enough to replace this line of code:

```
<p>author: <a href="{% url 'account_detail' pk = post.author.pk %}">{{ post.author }}</a></p>
```